# My private ssh key suddenly requires a passphrase (which I don't have)

Tags: ssh, encryption, security

I have always used my ssh key without a passphrase. The last time I used it was yesterday.

**But now, it suddenly requires a passphrase**:

```
> ssh-keygen -y
Enter file in which the key is (/home/vincentrolfs/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase: 
Load key "/home/vincentrolfs/.ssh/id_rsa": incorrect passphrase supplied to decrypt private key
```

**The private key apparently has been unchanged for months (since I first created it):**

```
> stat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  File: /home/vincentrolfs/.ssh/id_rsa
  Size: 1766        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 10305h/66309d   Inode: 933913      Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: ( 1000/vincentrolfs)   Gid: ( 1000/vincentrolfs)
Access: 2020-05-27 13:03:14.278893290 +0800
Modify: 2019-11-28 05:16:54.391995203 +0800
Change: 2019-11-28 05:16:54.391995203 +0800
 Birth: -
```

**The access permissions seem correct (600):**

```
> ls -l ~/.ssh
total 28
-rw-r--r-- 1 vincentrolfs vincentrolfs   156 Apr 28 14:05 config
-rw------- 1 vincentrolfs vincentrolfs  1766 Nov 28 05:16 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 vincentrolfs vincentrolfs   414 Nov 28 05:16 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 vincentrolfs vincentrolfs 13706 Apr 28 13:40 known_hosts
```

***Why does my ssh key suddenly require a passphrase? Should I be worried?***

EDIT: I used the backup service deja-dup for the first time yesterday and I believe it has something to do with it.

Comment: Mine look a little different with known_hosts having `-rw-------` as well. Did you check the permissions of `.ssh` itself? When playing with deja-dup, did you try out a restore?

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Comment: Does a blank password work as the passphrase?

Comment: @Idias No, it doesn't. I know that a "blank passphrase" is the same as "no passphrase" for ssh keys. Unfortunately that's not it in this case. Thanks for your suggestion.